# Send several request to get the final response or hold the first request?

Tags: java, rest, response

I am designing an API REST service that needs some times to response.
I want to know which way is better, sending several requests to get the final response or hold the request until the response is ready.
For example,

There are 120 students in a school and it takes 1 minute to get all the names of students.

Is it good to send a request every 10 seconds to get 20 students name until the we get 120 students . or hold the request and response after 1 minute with 120 students ?

(note that some browsers and httpClients timeout the request after 1min so it is risky)
(note that sending more request may be detected as DOS Attack )

Comment: i don't know what is you exact need, But for get API you can use pager concept. there you can define the limit like 10 students data in one response like that

Comment: Where is the data stored?

Comment: You can use pagination..

Comment: Agree with @pkgajulapalli . You could use a caching layer if the data retrieval takes a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions like that, I make lists of pro/con and then look at the results. Often, when creating those lists, a much better solution emerges.

There is no clear technical benefit for either.

Will users think that the service is down and reload the page when the requests take a minute? That would really create DDoS attack.

Will users read all 120 entries? Google just returns a few because experience shows that most people read the top 3.

Why does it take so long? Wrong indexes in the database? Or are you loading too much data? Maybe just getting the student's names and departments and year could be enough. Or create a job that keeps a view table where all the necessary data for your query is joined in a single table. That way, loading the data will take just a few ms.

Or how about loading 20, display them and wait whether the user scrolls down (keywords "infinite scrollers"). Another option is paging (load 20 elements and show next/previous buttons).